# Postgres nested if in case query

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, case

Could you tell my why the following isnt working in postgres sql?:

```
See updated code below
```

UPDATE:

I expect the query to return "0.30" as float.
This construct is only for testing purposes, i have some complex querys which depend on this conditional structure... BUt i dont know how to fix it..

Result is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 4:     if 1=1 then
```

UPDATE:

This construction appears in a function... so I want to do following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_test(myvalue integer) RETURNS float AS $$
  BEGIN
    select (
      case (select '1')
      when '1' then
        if 1=1 then
          0.30::float
        else
          0.50::float
        end
      else
         1.00::float
      end
    );
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select f_test(1) as test;
```

Error message see above.

Comment: use proper language, no need to use anything beyond pg here.

Comment: define "isnt working". What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: What is the actual output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `IF expr THEN result ELSE result END` syntax for normal SQL queries in Postgres. As there is neither an `IF()` function as in MySQL, you have to use `CASE`:

```
select (
  case (select '1')
  when '1' then
    case when 1=1 then 0.30::float else 0.50::float end
  else
     1.00::float
  end
);
```

Comment: Yes, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: No no, that is for stored procedures. For them there is one in MySQL, too, but *not* for normal SQL.

Comment: Ive updated my post, i use this code in a function... so it should work?

Comment: No, you are still *inside* the SELECT. These are the conditional expressions you can use in normal queries: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: This confused me for a while too. PostgreSQL has an `IF` control statement, however, it is only for use inside functions. For queries, you *MUST* use `CASE`.

Comment: Upvoted for showing me how to nest  multiple `CASE` statements in postgres.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve with this function, but here's a working version.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_test(myvalue integer) RETURNS float AS $$
BEGIN
    IF myvalue = 1 THEN
            IF 1=1 THEN
                    RETURN 0.30::FLOAT;
            ELSE
                    RETURN 0.50::FLOAT;
            END IF;
    ELSE
            RETURN 1.0::FLOAT;
    END IF;
END;
```

The function returns 0.3 if input value is 1, otherwise it'll return 1. **Edit:** Note that 0.5 is never returned by the function.

Comment: It only a test function without sense.. But I have complex queries which depend on this conditional structure.. I will try your answer... THanks